# How to display a notification whenever excel or word is opened in my computer

Tags: php, .net, excel, windows, vba

I want to know if it is possible to display a message/ notification in my computer whenever I open excel or word file within sub directory of a specific directories. 
Like

```
Main_directory/sub1/abc.xlxs
Main_directory/sub2/abcd.xlxs
Main_directory/sub3/abcdd.docx
```

If any of this file is opened or closed then display a notification / message.

Currently I know using PHP and I think something like this will be made in .net/ vba . 
Can somebody please suggest how it can be done , if it is possible. 
Currently using windows platform.

Edit: I found this http://www.ozgrid.com/VBA/excel-add-in-create.htm

Comment: please check this link [link](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/AppEvent.aspx)

Comment: It is possible by using File System Filter Driver. You can read about it here: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/43586/File-System-Filter-Driver-Tutorial If you don't have knowledge of C/C++ and Windows Internals, it will be very hard way

Comment: Or, second way, you can start windows file audit for your directory, create trigger in Task Scheduler for this events and execute program in case of access to files in your directory. This software can analyze windows log, and show notification. But just for opening files, not closing.

Comment: I was thinking to create an excel addin http://www.ozgrid.com/VBA/excel-add-in-create.htm